# Running Java application on Ubuntu server

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, deployment, jetty

How can I successfully deploy a Java application (with Wicket FW and embedded Jetty) that I am currently developing on Eclipse-Windows to an Ubuntu 12.04 server and run it there? I couldn't export a .war file for running it under Jetty since the project is not seen as a web application (it says "Module name is invalid" when I try).

If I manage to do so, I also want to access and manipulate source code on that server with Eclipse. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using embedded Jetty, then you can't export a WAR -- the whole point is that Jetty will be launched within your app, so you should export a JAR.

As far as editing code on the server, that doesn't sound like it would be possible, since you'll be running the compiled JAR.

Comment: Can I run my application with embedded Jetty as it is without exporting .war ?